# selenium webdriver to use data from the visible rows only in a webtable

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, html-table

The Siebel web application has a table containing about 200K user records, but displays 10 records at a time. There is a Search functionality to fetch one specific user id and display in the same table structure. So, when I search one user id, it displays only one record. Problem is that if I use xpath to find a column on that single record which is displayed after the search and try to getText() to get the value of that column, I am not getting the correct value. Instead I am getting the value from the original table data which is not visible now.

My code to get data of the td[3] is as below:

```
String cellValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='s_1_l']/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")).getText();
System.out.println(cellValue);
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

HTML of the webtable after the search with user id = "UX22983221" is below:

```
<div class="ui-jqgrid-bdiv" style="height: 339px; width: 1339px;">
<div style="position:relative;">
<div></div>
<table id="s_1_l" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" tabindex="0" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="true" aria-labelledby="" style="width: 1339px;" summary="Employee List" datatable="1">
<tbody>
<tr class="jqgfirstrow" style="height:auto" role="row">
<tr id="1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-state-highlight" tabindex="-1" role="row" style="height: 32px;" aria-selected="true">
<td aria-describedby="s_1_l_cb" style="text-align:center;display:none;" role="gridcell">
<td id="1_s_1_l_Last_N" title="" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell" aria-labelledby="s_1_l_Last_N s_1_l_altLink">
<td id="1_s_1_l_First_N" title="Man--Product Admin" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell" aria-labelledby="s_1_l_First_N">Man--Product Admin</td>
<td id="1_s_1_l_Job_ti" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell" title="" aria-labelledby="s_1_l_Job_Ti"> </td>
<td id="1_s_1_l_Log_Name" title="UX22983221" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell" aria-labelledby="s_1_l_Log_Name">UX22983221</td>
<td id="1_s_1_l_Resp" title=" Product Adm" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell" aria-labelledby="s_1_l_Resp s_1_l_altmvg"> Product Adm</td>
<td id="1_s_1_l_Po" title=" CAN SE_2D14403" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell" aria-labelledby="s_1_l_Po s_1_l_altmvg"> CAN SE_2D14403</td>
<td id="1_s_1_l_Inte_User_Flag" title="Unchecked" style="text-align:center;" role="gridcell" aria-labelledby="s_1_l_Inte_User_Flag s_1_l_altCheckBox">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show the original table? Does it exist in DOM? What is your expected text and what is the actual text that you got?

Comment: Are you trying to extract the text `Man--Product Admin` when you search search with user id = "UX22983221" ? Please format the `HTML` in the question area as per the actual `HTML` using the HTML formatter for better analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all know the difference between relative vs absolute xPath. You are trying to get element using common and absolute xPath which is common for all user. Instead use relative xPath.

Absolute xPath: uses complete path from the root element to the target element.

Relative xPath: simply by referencing the element.

Your xPath should be `".//*[@id='s_1_l']/tbody/tr[@class='jqgfirstrow']/td[contains(text(),'%s')]"`

in java file,

```
String cellValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(urXpath, userID))).getText();
```

here you just need to replace user id and you will get that `td` element.

Comment: Thank you Sanjay Bhimani. I got the answer. I guess you made a typo in your answer. So I replaced the class name in your suggested xpath as 'ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-state-highlight' and I got the answer.

Comment: @Sanjay Glad to help.